# how sockets or communication channels are maintained in distibuted system

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am new to distributed systems, and came to this problem once needed to deploy a gRPC service to kubernetes (GKE). As far as I know, when a client initiate an rpc, it creates a long lasting http2 connection and further calls are multiplexed on it. I like to send/push notifications or similar messages to the client through this connection. If I deploy to multiple pod, then the connections are spread across them, and not sure what is the best way to locate the instance where the channel is registered to the client. A possible solution could be, as soon as user initiate a connection, keep a reference of clientId and pod ip (or some identification) in a centralized service and other pods lookup the pod and forward the message to it. Is something like is advisable or is there an existing solution for this? I am unfamiliar with this space and any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Edit: (response to @mebius99)

While looking at deploying option, I stumbled upon GKE, and other cloud deployment options were limited because of my use of gRPC/http2. Thanks for mentioning service discovery , and that or service mesh might be an option. With gRPC, client maintains a long lived connection to a single pod. So, I want every pod to be able to query, based on unique clientId (clients can do an initial register rpc call), which pod is it connected, so can make use of this connection and also a way pods to forward the message between them. So, something like when I get a registration call from client, I update the central registry about the client and pod ip, then look it up from any pod and forward package to it so it further forward to client through the existing streaming connection.  You guiding me to the right direction, please let me know above is possible in container environment.

thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit why the Kubernetes Service concept and [service discovery](https://dzone.com/articles/kubernetes-service-discovery) don't work in your case? Is the question about traffic multiplexing / routing / balancing in Kubernetes or mainly about keeping connection state in a stateless environment the Kubernetes actually is?

Comment: thanks @mebius99 . While looking at deploying option, I stumbled upon GKE, and other cloud deployment options were limited because of my use of gRPC/http2. Thanks for mentioning service discovery , and that or service mesh might be an option. With gRPC, client maintains a long  lived connection to a single pod. So, I want every pod to be able to query based on clientId, where is it connected, so can make use of this connection and also a way pods to forward the message between them. You guiding me to the right direction, please let me know above is possible in container env.

Comment: Supposedly the [External HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) should fit your needs. That is why I have asked about applying in-built Kubernetes ingress. But, if you need something more sophisticated, Envoy proxy + NLB could be a solution, as @bells17 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745025/11602913).

Comment: @mebius99 thanks again for your suggestions. Hope my needs are clear from the above edit. 1. A way to check which pod a client is connected based on unique clientId 2. A way to quey from my application, the pod (id/ ip) based on clientId 3. A way to forward data/message from a pod to another from my application code. Please provide it as an answer, I will accept it. My main block now is how to do all this at application level, and how to keep a global index so all pods can query it. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to start from the [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) concept and [Service discovery](https://dzone.com/articles/kubernetes-service-discovery). The [External HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) should fit your needs.

In case you need something more sophisticated, [Envoy proxy + Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy) could be a solution, as is [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745025/11602913) here.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea, You can use Envoy proxy.
If you are using GKE, these posts are helpful.

- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/grpc-gke-nlb-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to implement some kind of Pub-Sub system.

You must do some back-of-envelop calculation of the scale, such as how many clients, how many messages per second first.

Then you can choose whether to implement yourself or pick an off-the-shelf system, such as https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/google-cloud-pub-sub-grpc.html

Comment: thanks for your input. For occasional notification, I could use FCM (cloud messaging ,..), but since I have a persistent socket connection, I would better off using it than introducing additional complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add more explanations to the existing answers here.

Since requests in HTTP/2 is multiplexed (multiple requests can be active on the same connection at any point in time), requests will be just pinned to a single Kubernetes pod. Hence, we need to configure a service mesh to shift from connection-based balancing to request-based balancing. Envoy Proxy mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745025/11602913) is one example.

I'd recommend everyone to read this good article from Kubernetes blog https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears.